# How to make textures made in Blender appear in Unity3d?

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, import, unity

So I am modeling a truck to be used in Unity. I colored different parts of the truck, but when I apply UV texture, it doesn't show up in Unity, but the colors do. What am I doing wrong, how can I make UV textures show in Unity? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of an off-topic, but related to Blender so makes sense to explain here too. Adding a UV texture from blender to your model in Unity is fairly simple, no more than dragging and and dropping the texture on to your model.

Here's an example of a model created, UV mapped and textured in blender:
[image: Blender]

Now to add to unity with the UV texture, all I needed to do is add the model from the project browser, then drag the UV texture file on top of it. Unity will automatically create or assign a material to the model, with the texture mapped to it. You can then edit the material properties in Unity.

[image: Unity]

Comment: Fantastic answer! I got it to work by saving as .fbx then moving the fbx file into the Unity editor window. Then I took my texture (PNG) and dragged it onto my model (a box in the shape of a brick for starters) and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you will have to import your texture to Unity as well as your model, then edit the object you have imported and its material. You often have to reassign the texture to the material inside of Unity to make the texture appear.